# RStudio server home directory

Tags: r, rstudio-server

I've just installed the RStudio server, which is now up and running. What I'm trying to work out is where on my Linux server the data gets stored. E.g. if in an RStudio session I save a file in a Home/my data/ directory, where can I find that on my server??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually in the home directory of the user that's logged into RStudio Server. So, if you're logged in as Mike, the files should normally be somewhere in `/home/Mike`, or any subdirectory. If you're not sure where you are exactly, use the `getwd()` command (or `system("pwd")` in your R console to find out.